# An old chesnut - add featured image to category list

Tags: image, categories

I have this code (I pinched it from here):

```
 <?php
    if (is_category()) {$this_category = get_category($cat);}
    ?>

    <?php

    if($this_category->category_parent)
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0
    &title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent.
    "&echo=0"); else
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=4&show_count=0
    &title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID.
    "&echo=0"
    );
    if ($this_category) { ?> 
 <ul>
<?php echo $this_category; ?>
 </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Which correctly returns:

```
 ParentCatA
 ChildCatA1
 ChildCatA2
 ChildCatA3
 ParentCatB
 ChildCatB1
 ChildCatB2
 etc
```

What I can't do is add the featured image to each Parent or Child as a thumbnail (after which, I'll want to add the last, up to, 12 posts to each Child)

I don't want to use a plugin for this

Help, please